# Python: Return First value based on dates for each product

Tags: python, pandas, apply, pandas-loc

I am looking for an iterative way of creating a subset of my pandas dataframe based on the date and product.  I would like to keep the first row for each product within a 2 week window.

So for df A:

```
Date,Product,Return
1/1/2020,ABC,0.00993
1/2/2020,ABC,0.04231
1/4/2020,ABC,0.04231
1/30/2020,ABC,0.04231
2/20/2020,ABC,0.01408
6/15/2020,XYZ,0.04868
6/16/2020,XYZ,0.05284
6/19/2020,XYZ,0.05284
6/25/2020,XYZ,0.01578
8/25/2020,XYZ,0.03248
9/25/2020,XYZ,0.03248
10/12/2020,XYZ,0.0375
12/2/2020,XYZ,0.02589
6/11/2020,EFG,0.02589
7/13/2020,EFG,0.02589
7/17/2020,EFG,0.02859
7/21/2020,EFG,0.02084
7/27/2020,EFG,0.05154
7/29/2020,EFG,0.05154
9/8/2020,EFG,0.0616
9/14/2020,EFG,0.04092
9/18/2020,EFG,0.01578
9/22/2020,EFG,0.03248
6/9/2020,ASD,0.03248
```

I want DF B returned:

```
Date,Product,Return
1/1/2020,ABC,0.00993
1/30/2020,ABC,0.04231
2/20/2020,ABC,0.01408
6/15/2020,XYZ,0.04868
8/25/2020,XYZ,0.03248
9/25/2020,XYZ,0.03248
10/12/2020,XYZ,0.0375
12/2/2020,XYZ,0.02589
6/11/2020,EFG,0.02589
7/13/2020,EFG,0.02589
7/27/2020,EFG,0.05154
9/8/2020,EFG,0.0616
6/9/2020,ASD,0.03248
```

My total dataframe has 10k products, I tried using .loc to create a variable based on the datetime/time delta but it could be based on dates for prior products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some way to group them by the week difference.  I suggest converting the date to week of year (52 week format), group by product, and get the `diff()` between each week of that product.  Using this we can calculate which diffs are greater than one and use `cumsum()` to increment the group so they aren't together.  The final columns 'c' is you extra grouping column.  Group on `product` and `c` and use `.head(1)` to get the first value per group.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1/1/2020','1/2/2020','1/4/2020','1/30/2020',
  '2/20/2020','6/15/2020','6/16/2020','6/19/2020','6/25/2020',
  '8/25/2020','9/25/2020','10/12/2020','12/2/2020','6/11/2020',
  '7/13/2020','7/17/2020','7/21/2020','7/27/2020', '7/29/2020',
  '9/8/2020','9/14/2020','9/18/2020','9/22/2020','6/9/2020'],
 'Product': ['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','XYZ','XYZ',
  'XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','EFG','EFG','EFG',
  'EFG','EFG','EFG','EFG','EFG','EFG','EFG','ASD'],
 'Return': [0.00993,0.04231,0.04231,0.04231,0.01408,0.04868,
  0.05284,0.05284,0.015780000000000002,0.03248,0.03248,
  0.0375, 0.025889999999999996,0.025889999999999996,
  0.025889999999999996,0.028589999999999997,
  0.02084,0.051539999999999996,0.051539999999999996,
  0.0616,0.04092,0.015780000000000002,0.03248,0.03248]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(by='Date').reset_index(drop=True)
df['week'] = df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week
df['c'] = df.groupby('Product')['week'].diff().fillna(0).gt(1).astype(int).cumsum()

df = df.groupby(['Product','c']).head(1)

df.drop(columns=['week','c'], inplace=True)
```

Output

```
Date    Product Return
0   2020-01-01  ABC 0.00993
3   2020-01-30  ABC 0.04231
4   2020-02-20  ABC 0.01408
5   2020-06-09  ASD 0.03248
6   2020-06-11  EFG 0.02589
7   2020-06-15  XYZ 0.04868
11  2020-07-13  EFG 0.02589
16  2020-08-25  XYZ 0.03248
17  2020-09-08  EFG 0.06160
21  2020-09-25  XYZ 0.03248
22  2020-10-12  XYZ 0.03750
23  2020-12-02  XYZ 0.02589
```